# Get return value in Lambda function

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a function call implemented using lambda which insert a row in postgres database using jooq library.

Below is the code:

```
  dslContext.transaction(
    c -> {
        this.postgresService.insertData(c, table, map);
    });
```

where c of type org.jooq.Configuration.

The code works properly & inserts a record in table & returns the inserted record. How can I access the 
returned primary key out of the lambda function.

This is the function to insertData :

```
public Record insertData(
        Configuration configuration, Table<? extends Record> table, Map<TableField<? extends Record, ?>, Object> map
    )
    {
        return DSL.using(configuration)
            .insertInto(table)
            .set(map)
            .returning()
            .fetchOne();
    }
```

Comment: what does the `transaction` method accepts?

Comment: @Aris it accepts org.jooq.TransactionalRunnable

Answer (score 6):

Just use `transactionResult`:

```
String primaryKey = dslContext.transactionResult(
  (Configuration c) -> {
    return this.postgresService.insertData(c, table, map);
  });
```

Comment: @usr_11 try now with explicit type of `c` and explicit return

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper class for storing the retrieved value:

```
class PrimaryKeyWrapper{
    Record primaryKey;

    public void setPrimaryKey(Record primaryKey) {
      this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    public Record getPrimaryKey() {
     return primaryKey;
    }
  }
```

And use and instance of that class for store this value from inside the lambda function:

```
PrimaryKeyWrapper primaryKeyWrapper = new PrimaryKeyWrapper();

dslContext.transaction(
c -> {
    Record primaryKey = this.postgresService.insertData(c, table, map);
    primaryKeyWrapper.setPrimaryKey(primaryKey);

});
```

Finally you can obtain the value from outside:

```
primaryKeyWrapper.getPrimaryKey();
```